# No VNC extension on display :1

Tags: 18.04, vnc, tightvncserver

On Ubuntu 18.04 I ran `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`. I then run `vncserver` which gives

```
New 'X' desktop is user:1

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /home/user/.vnc/user:1.log
```

as output. When I run `more /home/user/.vnc/user:1.log` I get

```
23/10/18 00:27:27 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
23/10/18 00:27:27 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
23/10/18 00:27:27 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
23/10/18 00:27:27 All Rights Reserved.
23/10/18 00:27:27 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
23/10/18 00:27:27 Desktop name 'X' (user:1)
23/10/18 00:27:27 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
23/10/18 00:27:27 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
No VNC extension on display :1
Killing Xtightvnc process ID 5196
```

I have no idea on how to resolve this issue and cannot find anything on `No VNC extension on display :1`.

Comment: Did you ever find answer to this?

Comment: @costa No, unfortunately not. And as you can see, nobody answered this question up until now (2020-06-03, 14:49).

Comment: I ended up using tigervncserver.

Comment: @costa Yeah I also heard of it. Hope it solves your problem. Good that you suggest it here for other people reading this post.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed `tigervnc` before `tightvnc`, it has replaced some files inside `/etc/X11/`. `/etc/X11/Xvnc-session` in particular, which will now call `vncconfig`, that in turn writes this message. `vncconfig` is not part of `tightvnc`, so it will silently die.

To fix this you will have to replace the contents of `/etc/X11/Xvnc-session` with the contents of `~/.vnc/xstartup` or with a call to `~/.vnc/xstartup`.

Comment: This solution also works on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score -1):

This cures the font problem but there is still the problem of display :1 not being recognised

apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
apt-get install xfonts-100dpi