# Grey screen with Ubuntu 20.04 and tightVNC

Tags: 20.04, gnome, remote-desktop, vnc

I followed [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/setup-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-linux/) to try to connect to my Ubuntu 20.04 machine from my Windows machine; installed tightVNC, changed the xstartup file to show the default Gnome desktop. I start the server with `vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24`.

When I try to connect with VNC viewer however, I see only a blank grey screen. The logs have this line:

`/home/username/.vnc/xstartup: 2: def: not found`

How can I fix this?

edit: I removed the `def` on line 2 of the `xstartup` file and that 'not found' message has gone from the logfile, but I still see a grey screen...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086246/no-vnc-extension-on-display-1 helped me after accidentally installing tigervnc before tightvnc

Answer (score 1):

Please post your xstartup file so we can see what you've actually configured.

The guide is for configuring an Xfce4 desktop, so I am assuming that's what you meant until you include xstartup contents in post.

I added `startxfce4` to the end as instructed [here](https://serverspace.us/support/help/install-tightvnc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/) and works for me.

My xstartup file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
vncconfig -iconic &


# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession

startxfce4
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped.